# Frequently having OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've a django app running on an Apache server on an AWS EC2 instance. I have a Ubuntu AMI. I'm frequently getting this error and I resolve it by restarting the mysql server `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

I've no clue why I'm getting the error, how can I resolve it for good ?

Comment: You resolved ? or You want to resolve ?

Comment: I resolved it by restarting the server. But how do i resolve such that it doesn't happen again? Because it has happened 3 times already within 2 weeks so restarting doesn't seem like a permanent fix

Comment: the issue seems to be on mysql side since django has no power to shut down mysql server. did you check mysql or syslog logs, etc?

Comment: Look at MySQL logs, switch to IP (instead of local sock), and/or switch to RDS. I assume this is a production database, given how 3 outages sound painful.

Comment: what type of EC2 instance are you using ?  t1.micro (600 Mb) and t2.micro (1 Gb) might be too small for hosting both Django and MySQL.  You will need a swap file to create some virtual memory.  Learn more about Swap Files for Ubuntu at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I'm using t2.small How do I know if it's too small ? Where I can check if I'm maxing out ?

Comment: Check current memory usage with 'top' or 'free' and be sure you enable a swap as described above